# How to send an array as a post variable

Tags: arrays, perl, post, mojolicious

I'm using Perl and a Perl framework (not sure if that's important). What I'm trying to do is create an arbitrary amount of inputs in a form (so a user would select as many things as they want from a list) then send that as part of an HTTP post. Is there even a way to do that? If so, how would I retrieve that info in Perl?

Comment: You can only send bytes. You'll need to convert the array into bytes. JSON would probably do the trick nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to do something like this:

```
<form action="/test" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="elements[]" value="">
    <input type="text" name="elements[]" value="">
    <input type="text" name="elements[]" value="">
    <input type="text" name="elements[]" value="">
    <input type="text" name="elements[]" value="">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then when you submit the form you will get an array "elements[]" (or it could be only "elements" but with "[]" is more clear), that will have all the fields.

If you use **checkboxes**, you will get only the ones that are **selected**.

Or you could make a [selectbox with "multiple"](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp).

Comment: Thanks for the answer bliof, So if say, all of them were selected, what would the URL look like?

Comment: Well if you use **post** it will be '/test'. If you want to use **get** it look like `/test?elements='some_value'&elements='other_value'&....`. P.s. I've changed the answer a bit.